# Differentiate $y=\tan^3 (5x+4)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiate

> $$y= \tan^3 (5x+4).$$

So I know we have to use the product rule, but since I haven't done this for a while, can someone please show me how?
THANKS!

Comment: You could use the product rule, though this would be silly. First write
$$
\tan^3(5x+4) =(\tan(5x+4)\tan(5x+4))\tan(5x+4).
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t have a product: you have a composite function, so you need the chain rule. At the outermost level your function is a cube: it’s the cube of $\tan(5x+4)$. Thus, you begin by using the power rule to differentiate the cube of something

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\big(\tan(5x+4)\big)^3=3\tan^2(5x+4)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\big(\tan(5x+4)\big)\;.$$

Now you have to differentiate the tangent:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=3\tan^2(5x+4)\cdot\sec^2(5x+4)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(5x+4)\;.$$

Can you finish it from there?

**[The Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):** If $y=f\big(g(x)\big)$, then

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f\,'\big(g(x)\big)\cdot g'(x)\;.$$

Another way to say this is that if $y=f(u)$, where $u$ is some function of $x$, then to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ you first differentiate as if $y$ were a function of $u$, getting $f\,'(u)$, and then multiply that result by $\frac{du}{dx}$.

Comment: I guess you have forgotten the square in the tan function

Comment: @noether: Thanks very much for catching the typo.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott could you also please post the chain rule formula?

Comment: @RedQueen10101: Done, together with a link to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule seems more appropriate than the product rule (I actually don't know how you'd use the product rule!). Apply the chain rule to $f(x)=5x+4$, $g(x)=\tan x$, and $h(x)=x^3$ to differentiate $h\circ g\circ f$. Remember:

**Chain Rule**: $(h\circ g\circ f)'(x)=h'(g(f(x)))g'(f(x))f'(x)$.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have to use the chain rule. Brian has already explained it better.

$\frac{df(g(x))^a}{dx} =  af(x)^{a-1} \cdot f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$

$y' = 3 \tan^2(5x+4) \cdot \sec^2(5x+4) \cdot 5$