# Differentiate $\ln(\cos2x)$ With respect to $x$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to differentiate $\,\ln(\cos2x)$.

Can someone please explain how to do this question? Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the chain rule?

Comment: Yes, could you please show me how to apply it?

Comment: It's the same as [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450269/differentiate-sin-sqrtx21-with-respect-to-x?rq=1), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450296/differentiating-tan-left-frac1-x2-1-right) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452633/differentiate-y-tan3-5x4).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hints:

- What is the derivative of $\ln u = \dfrac{1}{u}$
- What is the derivative of $\cos w = -\sin w$
- What is the derivative of $2x = 2$?

Can you put these together?

Okay, from the comments and the answers above, we have:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} \ln \cos 2x = \dfrac{1}{\cos 2x} (-\sin 2x) (2) = -2 \tan 2x$$

Do you see how we applied the chain rule?

Comment: ln u is 1/u    cos w is sinw and 2x is 2

Comment: @RedQueen10101 Correct. Can you put them together?

Comment: Im still uncertain of how

Comment: Yes thankyou i see now.

Comment: @RedQueen10101: (cos(w))' is -sin(w).

Comment: Yes, please don't write things like $\ln u = \frac1{u}$. Students are confused enough already. Either say $(\ln u)'$, or $\frac{d}{du}\ln u$, or else "the derivative of $\ln u$ is $\frac1{u}$".

Comment: Hey if i was to integrate tan2x dx. With the top bound being pi/6 and lower bound to be 0. How would i do it?

Comment: @ Amzoti don't worry i understand perfectly the wya you ecplained it.

Comment: @RedQueen10101: Do you know how to get the integral of $\tan 2x$? You should get $-1/2 log(cos(2 x))$. Now, you just use the limits of integration for the final result. Can you take it from there? The result will be $\ln(2)/2$

Comment: @Amzoti: Please, there's no need to be like that. I understand what you wrote, and the asker of the question does too. But if you read my comment, you'll see that not only did I not even begin to imply that something was offensive, but also that I think that writing things like $\ln u =\frac1{u}$ only helps further the confusion of students who write that when asked to differentiate $\ln u$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac d{dx} \ln(f(x)) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

$$f(x) = \cos 2x$$

$$f'(x) = (2x)'(-\sin 2x) = -2\sin 2x $$

$$\frac d{dx} \ln(\cos 2x) = \dfrac {-2\sin 2x}{\cos 2x} = -2\tan 2x$$

Comment: Excellent explanation. But may i ask what happened to the ln?

Comment: Recall that the $d/dx(\ln x) = \frac 1x$ here, we have $\ln(f(x)),$ so $[\ln(f(x))]' = \dfrac{f'(x)}{\cos 2x} $, where $f'(x) = (cos 2x)' = -2\sin 2x$

Comment: yes makes alot of sense

Answer (score 2):

Just use the chain rule.

The chain rule says that $g(f(x)) = f'(x)\cdot g'(f(x))$

Now, here $f(x)=\cos(2x)$ and $g(f(x))=\ln(\cos(2x))$.

**Remark:** $g'(f(x))$ means that first you form $g'(u)$ and then you plug in $f(x)$ like you're evaluating $g'(u)$ at $u=f(x)$.

More precisely, $g'(f(x))= \displaystyle {1 \over \cos(2x)}$ and as you already know $f'(x)= -2 \sin(2x)$. Now all you need to do is use chain rule. Then it becomes:

$g(f(x)) = f'(x)\cdot g'(f(x)) = -2 \sin(2x) \cdot \displaystyle {1 \over \cos(2x)} = -2 \tan(2x)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{du}\frac{du}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$$

put $f=\ln(\cos(2x))$ , $u=\cos(2x)$,$t=2x$

then $$\frac{d\ln(\cos(2x))}{dx}=\frac{d\ln(\cos(2x))}{d\cos(2x)}\frac{d\cos(2x)}{d2x}\frac{d2x}{dx}$$